# DateTimePicker Date Picking Error

Tags: c#, .net

I am using    DateTimePicker , i set it's customFormat property  to **dd/MM/yyyy**. In the system i have the format **M/d/yyyy**. How can i make the DateTimePicker independent from the systems one.

I have tried statements like

```
    DateInstance.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

but it's doesn't work.

It causes 2 problems for me:

1)  when i write statements such as

```
    DateInstance.Value = DateTime.Now;
```

it don't out it properly in the date time picker [for example : 7/5/2014(M/d/y) will be shown as 05/29/2017(dd/MM/yyyy)]

2) When i try to pick a date using mouse it only changes the day value while month and year stay as it's.

Comment: I guess you mean **dd/MM/yyyy.** (uppercase M)